# A trouble-some limit..

Tags: calculus, limits

For a unique value $r$, the value of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ n^r \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} \times\dots\times\frac{2n-1}{2n}$$ exists and is non-zero. For this value of $r$, what is the limit?

I've tried a few values but I haven't made much progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me how you got the value of 'r' and how you evaluated the limit?

Comment: I take it that by "unique value" you mean "unique positive value".

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{%
\lim_{n \to\infty}\pars{n^{r} \times \half \times {3 \over 4} \times\ldots\times
{2n - 1 \over 2n}}.\quad}$ $ r = ?$.

> \begin{align}
> &\ln\pars{n^{r} \times \half \times {3 \over 4} \times\ldots\times
> {2n - 1 \over 2n}}
> =r\ln\pars{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{2k - 1} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{2k}
> \\[3mm]&=r\ln\pars{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over 2k}}
> \\[3mm]&=r\ln\pars{n}
> + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over 2k}} + {1 \over 2k}}
> - \half\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \ln\pars{n}} - \half\,\ln\pars{n}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pars{r - \half}\ln\pars{n}
> + \overbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over 2k}} + {1 \over 2k}}}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{converges when}\ n \to \infty}}
> - \half
> \overbrace{\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \ln\pars{n}}}
> ^{\ds{\to \gamma\ \pars{~\mbox{Euler constant}~} \atop \mbox{when}\ n \to \infty}}
> \end{align}

This expresión converges when $\color{#0000ff}{\Large r = \half}$

In particular, $\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over 2k}} + {1 \over 2k}} = \half\,\gamma - \half\,\ln\pars{\pi}}$. Then,
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{n \to\infty}\pars{n^{1/2} \times \half \times {3 \over 4} \times\ldots\times
{2n - 1 \over 2n}}
=\exp\pars{-\,\half\,\ln\pars{\pi}} = {1 \over \root{\pi}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$n^r\times\frac{\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}\cdot (n-1)!}}{2^n\cdot n!}=n^r\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}\cdot n!\cdot (n-1)!}$$
Now use [Stirling's formula](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%91%E4%BC%BC)
$$n!\approx\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot n^n}{e^n}$$

Comment: but how does one determine the value of 'r'?

Comment: Just use wath mathlove suggested and look how behaves the term before the multiplication by n^r.